# Is there a way to write HTML directly into Outlook message body?

Tags: html, outlook

Is there a way to enable html in the outlook new message editor that allows you to write HTML directly into the message body without having to attach the HTML email using the insert feature. In other words, I want to write the following into Outlook and have it send what you see below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Email Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want to use simple html like embedding an image or maybe adding bold text. Nothing else.

This is a Heading 
This is a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the `Inspector.WordEditor` property (returns an instance of the Word's Document object) to manipulate the text directly, e.g. using `Bookmark.Range.InsertFile`

Comment: How would I get that working on my Outlook. I just want to be able to copy and past a newletter as HTML and have it show up properly customers gmail

Comment: You want to do that programmatically? Or as a user?

Comment: As a user please.

Comment: Then this question really belongs at SuperUser, not at StackOverflow.